# Multiply recursiverly in r

Tags: r, while-loop, infinite-loop, apply, multiplication

Having the following matrix and vector.

```
x<-matrix(c(1,4,7,
         2,5,8,
         3,6,9), nrow = 3)
w <- c(1,1,1)
res <- c()
```

What is the **best way to multiply recursiverly** till obtain a desire sum of the results as exemplified:

```
res[1]<-w %*%x[1,]
res[2]<-w %*%x[2,]
res[3]<-w %*%x[3,]
res[4]<-w %*%x[1,]
res[5]<-w %*%x[2,]

sum(res)>1000 #Multiply recursiverly till the sum of the results sum(res) goes further than 1000.
```

Comment: You tagged it with "while loop". That'd be my recommendation.

Comment: @Frank I know that with a "while loop" could be done but I don´t know how. Can you show me with an example how to do it.

Comment: They're pretty much the same in every programming language. Here's an example to start from: https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Loops/While#R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do it **recursively**:

```
f <- function(x, w, res){
    if (sum(res)>1000)
        return(res)
    res <- c(res, x%*%w)
    f(x,w,res)
}
```

Call it with your pre-defined objects. That is:

```
f(x, w, res)
```

Which will give you:

```
# [1]  6 15 24  6 15 24  6 15 24  6 15 24  6 15 24  6 15 24  6 15 24  6 15 24  6 15 24  6 15 24  6 15 24  6 15 24  6 15 24  6 15 24  6 15 24  6 15 24  6 15 24  6 15 24  6 15 24  6 15 24  6
# [62] 15 24  6 15 24  6 15 24
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always have data on the same format then something along the lines

```
res <- min(floor(1000 / cumsum(rowSums(x)))) * cumsum(rowSums(x)) + cumsum(rowSums(x))
min(res[res>1000])
```

will give the answer to you without having to loop. Could be wrapped in a function to handle another value than 1000.

At least as how I understand your question

Comment: I would like to have values different than 1000. I just post this value as an example. Could you post how to wrap in a function.

Comment: Use the exact same approach as @m0h3n did - which also had 1000 hard-coded.