# Sum matrix recursively from previews operations

Tags: r, function, matrix, repeat

Having the following matrix and vector:

```
a<-matrix(c(1,4,7,
        2,5,8,
        3,6,9), nrow = 3)
b <- c(1,1,1)
```

How do I sum recursiverly over each line of the matrix **inside a funciton** till obtain a desired result **using last result to calculate next operation** as shown:

```
b<-b+a[1,]
b<-b+a[2,]
b<-b+a[3,]
b<-b+a[1,]
b<-b+a[2,]

sum(b)>100 # Sum recursiverly till obtain this result sum(b)>100
```

This operation looks similar to this answer [Multiply recursiverly in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39703542/multiply-recursiverly-in-r). However it uses results from previews operations to calculate next ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a recursive function to do what you're after,

```
# Sample Data
a<-matrix(c(1,4,7,
        2,5,8,
        3,6,9), nrow = 3)
b <- c(1,1,1)
```

We create a function that references itself with a value that increments modulo the number of rows

```
recAdd <- function(b, a, start = 1, size = NROW(a)) {
  if(sum(b) > 100) return(b)
  return(recAdd(b + a[start,], a, start = start %% size + 1, size))
}

> recAdd(b,a)
[1] 30 38 46
```

EDIT: Alternatively, here's a way with no recursion at all, which is much faster on large ratios of target number to sum of the matrix (but is slower on data of this size). Basically we get to take advantage of Euclid

```
nonrecAdd <- function(b, a, target = 100) {
  Remaining <- target - sum(b)
  perloop <- sum(a)
  nloops <- Remaining %/% perloop
  Remaining <- Remaining %% perloop
  if(Remaining > 0) {
    cumulativeRowsums <- cumsum(rowSums(a))
    finalindex <- which((Remaining %/% cumulativeRowsums) == 0)[1]
    b + colSums(a) * nloops +  colSums(a[1:finalindex,,drop = FALSE])
  } else {
    b + colSums(a) * nloops
  }
}
```